# Как декодировать данный JSON

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

у меня есть проблемы с JSON
Немогу декодировать JSON такого типа

```
{
"error": 0,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 14845,
        "title": "Текст новости",
        "teaser": "В этом году было выявлено 47 положительных проб.\r\n",
        "delay_date": "2018-12-11 03:03:00",
        "cat": {
            "category_id": 17,
            "language_id": "ru",
            "slug": "sport",
            "description": "",
            "title": "Новость",
        },
   }  
]
```

Делаю так:

```
    struct News_data: Decodable {
    let data: Article_Data

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let data = try container.decode(Article_Data.self, forKey: CodingKeys.data)
        self.data = data
    }
}

struct Article_Data: Decodable {
    let news : [News_arr]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case news = "news"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let news = try container.decode([News_arr].self, forKey: CodingKeys.news)

        self.news = news
    }
}

struct News_arr: Decodable{
    let title: String
    let image: String
    let delay_date: String
    let cat : Category
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case delay_date = "delay_date"
        case cat = "cat"
        case image = "image"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.title)
        let delay_date = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.delay_date)
        let image = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.image)
        let cat = try container.decode(Category.self, forKey: CodingKeys.cat)

        self.title = title
        self.delay_date = delay_date
        self.cat = cat
        self.image = image
    }
}

struct Category: Decodable {
    let cat_title: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case cat_title = "title"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let cat_title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.cat_title)


        self.cat_title = cat_title

    }
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите,
Что не так?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: В JSON у коллекции cat нет параметра title.

Comment: Простите, ошибся, параметр title есть

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос URL откуда берет JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот

```
struct NewsModel: Decodable {

    let error: Int
    let news: [NewsItem]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case news = "data"
        case error = "error"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        news = try container.decode([NewsItem].self, forKey: .news)
        error = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .error)
    }
}

 struct NewsItem: Decodable {

    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let teaser: String
    let delayDate: String
    let category : Category

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case title = "title"
        case delayDate = "delay_date"
        case teaser = "teaser"
        case category = "cat"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        teaser = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .teaser)
        delayDate = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .delayDate)
        category = try container.decode(Category.self, forKey: .category)
    }
}


 struct Category: Decodable {

    let id: Int
    let languageId: String
    let slug: String
    let description: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "category_id"
        case language = "language_id"
        case slug = "slug"
        case description = "description"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        languageId = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .language)
        slug = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .slug)
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает но когда хочу вывести получаю ошибку "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead." не подскажите как устранить?

Comment: а как выводите ?

Answer (score 1):

Намного проще будет если ты будешь использовать онлайн сервисы для декодирования https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift

Comment: Незнал что такое есть, спасибо большое!